# Filter images that are covered with my roi more than 80%

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, land-cover, imagecollection

This is my collection with (453 elements) in it which I firstly added `filterBounds(polygon)`:

```
var collection = collection_L5.merge(collection_L7).merge(collection_S2);
print(collection)
```

But many images have less than 20% or 50% coverage with my polygon.
I also used `ee.Filter.contains('.geo', polygon)`  to filter it but it returns 20 images and I know there are many more than this.

So I want to filter those that has coverage with my polygon less than 80%. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`filterBounds` returns true if any portion intersects the ROI.
`contains` returns true only if all portions intersect the ROI.

You get partial overlap percentage, compute the area of intersection and divide it by the total area of the image geometry.

```
var tol = 1000  // tolerance, in meters.
var results = collection.map(function(img) { 
   var overlap = img.geometry().intersection(ROI, tol)
   var ratio = overlap.area(tol).divide(img.geometry().area(tol))
   return img.set("coverage", ratio)
}).filter("coverage > 0.8")
```

(but IMO that's overkill.  It's easier to just negative buffer the ROI by 80% of the size of an image and use filterBounds).